# How to make fonts in Netbeans UML Editor smaller?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans6.7

On my mac OS 10.5, in Netbeans 6.7.1, the fonts in my class diagram look very chunky and huge. Can I set the font sizes globally somewhere? I'd like to make them all smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools > Options > Font & Colors, and click on th ellipsis button next to Font text box.